# Javascript, getting lots of elements and setting them to display none

Tags: javascript

i wish to grab a load of elements, check if their id contains 'other' or 'Other' and for those, set the display to none. This is what i have:

```
function Hide(div){
    var list;
    var i;
    list = document.getElementById(div).getElementsByTagName("input")
    for(i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        if(list[i].id.toString().indexOf("Other") != -1 || list[i].id.toString().indexOf("other") != -1){
            list[i].id.setAttribute("Style.display","none");
        }
    }
}
```

but .setAttribute... doesnt work and nor did .Style.display = "none"

Comment: Incidentally, in Prototype.js this would look like
 $(div).select('input[id*="other"]').invoke('hide');

That's why I use Prototype rather than vanilla JS. But that's not what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the style property of the **element** not the **string containing the id**!

```
list[i].style.display
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `style.display`, because '`display`' is a property of the `style` Object.
You should use:

```
list[i].style.display = 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `list[i].style.display`, **lower case**, set attribute to object itselft